# Calculate sum in array using used in object

Tags: arrays, object, for-loop

I am new to js and I want to calculate a sum in the array. The issue is that my array is sitting in object - game. Here is my code:

```
var game = {
    fullName: 'Mark Visp', 
    score: [110, 320, 50, 80],
    sumScore: function () {
        this.total = [];
        var total = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < this.score.length; i++) {
            total = total + this.score[i]; 
            } 
        return total
    }  
}  
game.sumScore();
console.log(game);
```

I am missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace with below code

```
var game = {
    fullName: 'Mark Visp', 
    score: [110, 320, 50, 80],
    total: 0,
    sumScore: function () {
        var _total = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < this.score.length; i++) {
            _total = _total + this.score[i]; 
            } 
        this.total = _total;
    }  
}  
game.sumScore();
console.log(game);
```